# Scroll only in one grid column with semanti-ui-react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-grid-scroll-t5ff4) I have a two-column grid, that I want to make only the right column scrollable. This means the left column/menu should not go out of the screen by scrolling on the browser.

by giving `position: fixed` to the left column and `marginLeft:somePixels` to the right column it somehow works but if the content stacks on the smaller resolution, the layout gets destroyed.

How can I achieve this with semantic `css` classes or a custom style

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to every element, from root to the container you want to scroll, the `height: 100%`.

Because it need to know what is the full dimension you need to scroll.

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-grid-scroll-forked-d8wsp?file=/index.js) is the sandbox fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, But I do not see any fixes, still both columns scroll together.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi try it now.